# Convert jcalendar Date into XMLGregorianCalendar Getting Null Value

Tags: java, date, datetime, null, gregorian-calendar

i have some problem, i just getting null value from jDateChooser in jCalendar.

This method is function to convert java.util.Date into XMlGregorianCalendar :

```
DatatypeFactory df;
public XMLGregorianCalendar function_ConvertAsXMLGregorianCalendar(Date date) {
    if (date == null) {
        System.out.println("Error on Function Convert Date into XML Gregorian Calendar");
        return null; 
    } else {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
        return df.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
    }
}
```

And this is 2 function which getStart and getEnd Dates.

```
private XMLGregorianCalendar getStartDate(){
    Date dateStarting  = jDateChooserStart.getDate();
    System.out.println("Date Start : " + dateStarting.toString());
    XMLGregorianCalendar cal = function_ConvertAsXMLGregorianCalendar(dateStarting);
    System.out.println("Converted Date : " + cal.toXMLFormat());
    return cal;
}

private XMLGregorianCalendar getEndDate(){
    Date dateEnding = jDateChooserEnd.getDate();
    System.out.println("Date End : " + dateEnding);
    return function_ConvertAsXMLGregorianCalendar(dateEnding);
}
```

Then i just place the method inside an object called schedule:

```
schedule.setStartDate(getStartDate());
schedule.setEndDate(getEndDate());
```

Result from Netbeans(v7.1)

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Frames.CreateSchedule.function_ConvertAsXMLGregorianCalendar(CreateSchedule.java:181)
at Frames.CreateSchedule.getStartDate(CreateSchedule.java:188)
at Frames.CreateSchedule.SubmitButtonActionPerformed(CreateSchedule.java:204)
at Frames.CreateSchedule.access$000(CreateSchedule.java:16)
```

what's wrong?

Thanks before.

**UPDATE ::**

I just change the function into this:

```
public XMLGregorianCalendar function_ConvertAsXMLGregorianCalendar(Date date) {
    if (date == null) {
        System.out.println("Error on Function Convert Date into XML Gregorian Calendar");
        return null; 
    } else {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
        DatatypeFactory df = null;
        return df.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2# ::**

After initializing the newInstance() method, i'm getting another error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

I just change the package name from

```
java.util.Date into java.SQL.Date
```

then casting:

```
Date dateStarting  = (Date) jDateChooserStart.getDate();
Date dateEnding    = (Date) jDateChooserEnd.getDate();
```

How to resolve this issue?

thanks again.

Comment: Youre still not instantiating `df`, see my update below.

Comment: yes, i need to instantiating the df var. thanks for your comment

Comment: hi there @Reimeus could you help me again? thanks

Comment: Sure, but perhaps in a new question posting?

Comment: hi @Reimeus i just posted in new question post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131068/error-casting-java-util-date-into-java-sql-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `df` is declared but not instantiated:

```
DatatypeFactory df;
```

from here:

```
df.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
^
```

You can use [DatatypeFactory.newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newInstance%28%29) to instantiate first, like so:

```
DatatypeFactory df = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
```

Comment: aha, thanks Reimeus. that's the answer. i need to create newInstance() first.

Answer (score 1):

Though not obvious without proper line numbers in your code, the most likely cause of the `NullPointerException` is the line:

```
  return df.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
```

with your `df` being null.  Where do you initialize this field?

Comment: yes, i just forgot to place the initialization method. @akf could you help me again? (update 2#) please. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly understanding your problem but seems to me this is an easy fix call your Calendar like this should work (i think).

```
Calendar timeStamp = new GregorianCalendar();
```