# error casting Java.Util.Date into Java.Sql.Date

Tags: java, datetime, time, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert java.util.date to java.sql.date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date)

I found error on my function, it shows error result after initializing the newInstance() method from DatatypeFactory df , I'm getting another error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

I just change the package name from

```
java.util.Date into java.SQL.Date
```

then casting:

```
Date dateStarting  = (Date) jDateChooserStart.getDate();
Date dateEnding    = (Date) jDateChooserEnd.getDate();
```

How to resolve this issue?

(post before: [Convert jcalendar Date into XMLGregorianCalendar Getting Null Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130680/convert-jcalendar-date-into-xmlgregoriancalendar-getting-null-value))

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's not possible to *cast* from `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date`. You need to *convert* from one type to the other instead:

```
java.util.Date utilStartDate = jDateChooserStart.getDate();
java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(utilStartDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 4):

From the class cast exception you can see that these are 2 distinct types and can't be cast the from one to the other. To convert from `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date`, you can use:

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```